# Multiple images and proper side-caption positioning

Tags: floats, lyx, captions, subfloats, minipage

I would like to put three images on one page (as one figure). First two of them stretched over 100% of textwidth and the third one over 50 % with the caption beside the third picture (to spare space). I was trying to achieve this with boxes inside the figure as you can see in the first screenshot of my lyx window. Boxes in the lower paragraph are set to 50 and 48 % width.
[image: screenshot]

However, in the result, the caption is not aligned properly after export (on the screenshot exported with "draft" option):
[image: result_1]

What I would like to achieve is alignment, which comes with "drop shadows" settings turned on on the box with caption, as you can see on the last screenshot (except I do not want the "drop shadow" effect! :)):
[image: result_2]
Please, do you have any suggestions for proper setup? Many thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Go into the settings of the two last minipages and change the vertical alignment of the box to Bottom:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Marian please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark at the top of the answer and give a +1 (if you feel it is deserved) by clicking on the up arrow.

Comment: @scottkosty Upvoting actually requires at least 15 reputation points, so Marian can't do that yet.